# How to make a grid with one style?

Tags: css, grid

i need simple grid, two columns, and indefinite number of rows. Is it possible to make it with one css style? I knwo how to make it with one for left column and another for right, but i really want to know if and how it can be done with one style since idea is that when i add another entry it automatically moves previous to next "cell".
For example content of A1 becomes B1, B1 becomes A2 etc...

Tnx!

Comment: could you post your image here

Comment: use nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd)

Comment: no, my reputation is too low to post images...
here's the simple code for final result:
<table> 
<tr> <td>A1</td> <td>B1</td></tr>
<tr> <td>A2</td> <td>B2</td></tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table is the wrong thing to be using here. Table cells can't drop to the next line. Instead, use divs that are either floated or set to `display: inline-block;` with a width close to `50%`. That way, they will sit side by side and stack in rows as you add more.

Here's a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
* {margin:0; padding: 0;}
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
.wrap {width: 80%; overflow: hidden; background: #f7f7f7; padding: 20px; margin: 20px auto;}
.wrap div {min-height: 200px; width: 48%; display: inline-block; padding: 20px; background: #e7e7e7; margin-bottom: 5px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: table was just to ilustrate an example. Thanx Ralph, that was just the thing i was looking for!

Comment: Ralph, when i fill the divs with pic and text, those on the right side are shifted down comparing to those on the left unless i have same ammount of text. I tried to level it with fixed height, but it's not responding ?

Comment: Ah yes, I should have added that in. It's nicer to work it out yourself anyway. :)